# Black code formatter line length ignore comment included

Tags: python, formatting, coding-style

So, it seems, that Black code formatter default `line-length` option also takes under consideration comments included in the line

For example

```
if some_very_long_variable_name_out_there_for_example is True: # just a random comment
    pass
```

Will produce in

```
if (
    some_very_long_variable_name_out_there_for_example is True
    ):  # just a random comment
    pass
```

, which is definitly correct in terms of black standard

However, the line `if some_very_long_variable_name_out_there_for_example is True:` is actually less than 88 symbols and I don't want my code to be kinda visually broken just because I added comment

Is there an option to disable such behaviour?

Comment: If the variable contains a boolean, no need of `is True`, then why do you have long names you shouldn't ?

Comment: When testing a `bool`, use one of `if var:` or `if not var:`.  It's *already* a `bool`.  You don't need to compare it to `True`.  Doing `if var is True:` makes no more sense then `if ((var is True) is True) is True:`   Why stop at one redundant layer when you can add 3 or more redundant layers?

Comment: I need no advices in checking bools guys, the question is simply about Black code formatter

Answer (score 2):

Note that currently Black remains the comment intact, even though its clearly over the line length limit. An open Issue being discussed is somewhat relevant, although not exactly the same:

> https://github.com/psf/black/issues/1713

But so far there is no PR planed or submitted on it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really answering your question, but I guess you could get into a habit of writing in this form instead:

```py
# just a random comment on the previous line
if some_very_long_variable_name_out_there_for_example is True:
    pass
```